# Devise: how to return 401 Unauthorized without redirect if user is not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Rails version: 4.0.13

Devise version: 3.2.0

When a user tries to view a page which they are not authorized to view, my application redirects them to a sign in page.

If the user is not signed in, I want to:

1. *Not* redirect the user to a new URL and
2. Return a '401 Unauthorized' response with an empty body

So far, I tried to override `authenticate_user!` like so:

```
class BaseApiController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def authenticate_user!
    head :unauthorized
  end
end
```

However, while this does return a '401 Unauthorized', it also redirects to the sign in URL first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off @vinyl's answer, the following will return a 401 without redirecting if the user is not signed in:

```
# lib/custom_failure.rb
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    http_auth
  end
end

# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
end
```

You can customize `respond` to redirect in some cases and throw 401 cases in others. For my use case, the following was sufficient:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    if request.env['REQUEST_PATH'].start_with?('/api')
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

I don't understand why overriding `authenticate_user!` did not work here.

Comment: Rails 5.2 and 6.0 do not use `request.env['REQUEST_PATH']`. And in any case, it's better to use the public methods provided for `ActionDispatch::Request` when available. Try using `request.original_fullpath.start_with?('/api')`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

This still redirects a user, although you can control where that redirect goes.

Comment: This looks like it's in the right direction, but is not enough for me to solve my issue. I'm investigating it more closely though.

Comment: I'm curious what you're expecting a user to see/experience when they try to access a URL protected by authentication if there's no redirect.  Are you working with an API only codebase?

Comment: No, some routes are API routes (begin with `/api/v1/`) and other routes are a normal Rails app. If a user is not logged in and tries to access an API route, I want them to see a 401 and not be redirected anywhere.